# Unable to stop window.onScroll from triggering even after component unmounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have 2 different kinds of `NavBar` components in my project: a `NavBarTransparent.jsx` that's only used in `index.jsx` (home page), and a `NavBar.jsx` that's used on all other pages.

Now, I have a function set to trigger each time the window scrolls in the `NavBarTransparent.jsx` component:

```
// components/NavBarTransparent.jsx

useEffect(() => {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollFunction);
});

const scrollFunction = () => {
    const nav = document.getElementById('nav');
    const overlay = document.getElementById('nav-overlay');
    const travel = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    const travelRem = travel / 16;
    const navHeight = 7 - (travelRem / 6);
    if (navHeight <= 4) {
      nav.style.lineHeight = `${4}rem`;
      overlay.style.opacity = 1;
    } else if (navHeight >= 7) {
      nav.style.lineHeight = `${7}rem`;
      overlay.style.opacity = 0;
    } else {
      nav.style.lineHeight = `${navHeight}rem`;
      overlay.style.opacity = (7 - navHeight) / 3;
    }
  };
```

The other navbar component (`NavBar.jsx`) does not have this event listener. However, the event listener still gets triggered when I visit, say, `/about` from `/` (client-side routing). Why is the listener getting hit when the other page doesn't even use that component?

The repo is up at https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/tree/master/web

Comment: global.window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollFunction);

Comment: I do not see `NavBarTransparent` file in your repo. Please show the full code of `NavBarTransparent` file

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the following:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if(transparent) { window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollFunction); }

    // returned function will be called on component unmount
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollFunction);
    }
  }, []);
```

Looks like window event listeners added before a component mounts must be explicitly removed before the component unmounts. I was adding the listener via the `useEffect` hook, but not unmounting it, hence the issue of persistent triggers. Now, I have used the `return()` snippet of `useEffect` (the Hooks equivalent of `componentWillUnmount`) to remove the listener and it works fine.

Also, am using `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect` because if you want to manipulate DOM and do so **before** browser paint, as is the case here, useLayoutEffect` is preferable.